# SQL Server Summary file with date/logic

Tags: sql-server, summary

I have a transaction detail table (SQL Server) where all product ID, transaction type (sale, rent, estimate), and date is recorded.
There are a few columns that are of interest for me: ID, Sale Date, Transaction type, amount
I want to create a summary file off of this table where:

1. Each row represents an ID# (group by IDNO)
2. Sale Date is selected as the date (TRDATE where transaction type is 'S' for sale)
3. Amount (this is the tricky part for me): I want the amount to be the sum of Sale amount AND any other transaction that occurred after the sale date for that product ID, regardless of their transaction type.

I have been able to query that, but only for one I need help creating that logic in SQL Server.

```
IDNO (ID#)
TRDATE (Transaction date) formatted as numeric ex. 20191012 (12 October 2019)
AMT (Amount)
TRCODE (Transaction code/type)
```

Here is a sample of the data:

[image: Data sample]

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results as tabular text to clarify your question. As it is, it is hard to tell what you exactly want.

Comment: @GMB Thanks for your response. I have added a sample of the data as an image. I couldn't post it as a formatted table or legible text.

Comment: The point of posting the data isn't so much so that we can see it, but so that we can copy/pasta it into a workable solution. And image is fine for seeing what the data looks like but I don't think anyone is going to type all that in.

Comment: @TechGnome I was not sure what's the best way to post. Here's a comma delimited version:

TRDATE,IDNO,TRCODE,AMT
20190228,15E1586,E,22333
20190228,15E1586,S,61061.65
20190220,15E1586,W,250
20190321,15E1586,C1,-36
20190329,15E1586,E,-622
20190305,15E1586,S,0
20190322,12F85302,T,52300
20190322,12F85302,S,69458
20190328,12F85302,W,-122
20180731,12F85302,C1,150
20190129,17875016,T,-15
20190129,17825046,W,-523
20190131,17875016,T,0
20190131,17825046,T,1500
20190131,17875016,S,79381.26
20190301,17825046,C1,42.5
20190301,17825046,C1,-562

Comment: @GMB Would you be able to look at the sample data and comment? Thanks

Comment: @Monib: you provided sample data, now what is your expected result?